# Add customize JSP in jasper report server

Tags: jasperserver

How can I add a customize page in jasper report server, I'm having the error JSP does not exist at the specified location, but it exists at that location on mytomcat.....

Comment: You can view sample at `$jasperreports-server-cp$\samples\java-webapp-sample` folder. And you can also find guides in `$jasperreports-server-cp$\docs` folder

Comment: Alex I have checked docs but didn't find any relevant source..

Comment: The JasperForge faq [have some info about how to start](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/FAQ#How_do_I_customize_the_look_and_feel_of_JasperServer.3F)

Answer (score 0):

After copying the JSP file in tomcat you have to copy in  "/WEB-INF/jsp" folder of Jasper server and then edit the report in jasperserver and add JSP page location in "Control and Resourses" property.